# Link to the upload folder

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I created a link in my column named "Download" in my table that will redirect to my "Upload" folder containing the files, but when i try to click the link it doesnt go the upload folder.

```
$i=1;
while ($rowList = mysqli_fetch_array($sqltran)) {
    $name = array(
        'num' => $i,
        'date'=> $rowList['date'],
        'memo'=> $rowList['memo'],
        'title'=> $rowList['title'],
        'file' => '<a href="' . $rowList['file'] . '" target="_blank">Download </a>'
    );

    array_push($arrVal, $name);
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by going to the "upload folder" ?

Comment: It should be whenever i click the "Download" link in my column it should go to my uploads folder containing the files

Comment: what is the content of `$rowList['file']` ?

Comment: What does the HTML for the `<a href=` tag say when you load it in the browser? Basic troubleshooting, such as sticking `?><pre><?php print_r($name);?></pre><?php` in your while loop will show you what data is inside the `$name` variable... Break the problem down to smaller pieces.

Comment: @varlogtim It goes to localhost/name/file.pdf instead of localhost/name/uploads/file.pdf is there something wrong with my script? 'file' => '<a href="' . $rowList['file'] . '" target="_blank">Download </a>'

Comment: Jay, that would mean that the value of `$rowList['file']` is `localhost/name/uploads/file.pdf` What is populating that SQL data? Do you possibly upload the file to the `uploads` directory and then move the file? Can you show the code that handles the upload?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/J1DBX2QC this is my code that handles the upload, the pdf files are properly stored in my uploads folder when i upload something, but when i check my sql data is says name.pdf instead of uploads/name.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Your href is linking to the file in your current directory. In line 7 of your code you are moving your uploaded file to the *uploads/* directory.

If you want to link to the files again you have to add the directory to your href:

```
<a href="uploads/'.$rowList['file'].'" target="_blank">Download </a>
```